# How to trim the display text of hyperlink in Excel

Tags: excel

I have some cells that contain hyperlinks. The hyperlinks have leading blanks. If I use TRIM, the result returned is just a text, not a hyperlink.

Is there a worksheet function (not vba) that can remove the leading blanks and retain the functionality of the hyperlink?

Example:
____Link1Text (where ___ are blanks and link1Text is a hyperlink in a cell).

Thank you.

Comment: For a function, you could try `=HYPERLINK(TRIM(A1))`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, thank you for your help. I tried your suggestion, it worked for trimming the leading blanks and maintaining the hyperlink look and feel, but when I click on the trimmed text, I get the message "Error can't open the file", although the original hyper link is working. Thx again.

Comment: Then use @pnuts suggestion

Comment: @NoChance to elaborate further, if `Link1Text` (without the leading spaces) is not the actual URL or full file path, then the Excel formula will not work.  You'll need a VBA routine to extract the actual hyperlink address.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, thank you. If you like to make this an answer, I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
=HYPERLINK(TRIM(A1))
```

However, if `Link1Text` (without the leading spaces) is not the actual URL or full file path, then the Excel formula will not work. You'll need a VBA routine to extract the actual hyperlink address.  If that is the case, then try this UDF (User Defined Function):

```
Function GetHyperlink(RG As Range) As String
    GetHyperlink = RG.Hyperlinks(1).Address
End Function
```

and then use this formula in the cell:

```
=HYPERLINK(GetHyperlink(A1),TRIM(A1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.